# Pass permitters to web service to load Infopath 2010 form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services

I have a request to designed infopath form to get data from externally running web servicer . In designed a form has 3 text boxes to user to enter 3 permitter that I can pass to web servicers to search user information .
And this will return multiple recodes .

im not sure how to do this ? Every time I load the form it gets all the use information and populate with repeat table.

what I need is to 
1.  User input parameters  3 text boxes 
2.  User click  search button to get information web service 
3.  Display output in reporting table

Appreciate your help

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is for a SOAP based service: http://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/calling-web-service-from-infopath-2010-with-parameters/

It demonstrates how to pass parameters to a service.

The same should apply for WCF.

Comment: Please add more details, this answer is very dependent on the link. If the link breaks it will be of no help to future readers

Comment: Hi Jared thanks for the reply . i manage to create infopath form and its working. but im having a issue when i deploy form to sharepoint 2010 ? below is my error .                               A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action would violate cross-domain restrictions. 
any solution to overcome this ?

Comment: So far i check 01 on CA "Allow cross-domain data access for user form templates that use connection settings in a data connection file"                                                02"Convert the Data Connection to .udcx file"                     .No luck !!! appreciate your help . Txns